# Conotação negativa para palavras que denotam simplicidade

Tags: significado, etimologia, sinônimos, figuras-de-linguagem

Pode-se notar no Português o caso de palavras que originalmente denotavam 'comum', 'simples', 'rotineiro'; porém, na contemporaneidade, possuem conotação, ou até significado próprio, negativo.

Exemplos seriam:

> vilão
>
> adjetivo substantivo masculino
>
> 1.
>   que ou o que reside em vila.
>   "homem v."
>
> 2.
>   que ou o que não pertence à nobreza; plebeu.
>   "origem v."
>
> 3.
>   fig. que ou aquele que é indigno, abjeto, desprezível.
>
> 4.
>   adjetivo
>   fig. rústico, rude, grosseiro.
>
> 6.
>   substantivo masculino
>   o personagem que representa o lado mau, nas peças teatrais, novelas e filmes.
>
> Origem
>   ⊙ ETIM lat.vulg. * villānus 'habitante de vila, casa de campo'

Vilão, etimologicamente denotando aquele que mora em vila, hoje pode significar representante do mau, ou, figurativamente, desprezível.

> ordinário
>
> adjetivo
>
> 1.
>   conforme ao costume, à ordem normal; comum.
>   "fatos o."
>
> 2.
>   que se repete regularmente, ou se faz presente a todo instante.
>   "o médico fazia visitas o. aos pacientes"
>
> 3.
>   sem brilho, sem destaque; medíocre.
>   "espírito o."
>
> 4.
>   de pouca ou má qualidade; inferior.
>   "tecido o."
>
> Origem
>   ⊙ ETIM lat . ordinarĭus,a,um 'posto por ordem, disposto conforme à regra, ao uso'

Aqui, nota-se que ordinário tinha tom até positivo, como algo que atende a padrões. Porém, hoje carrega pejoratividade.

> vil
>
> adjetivo de dois gêneros
>
> 1.
>   que tem pouco valor, não presta; reles, ordinário.
>   "pessoa v."
>
> 2.
>   que custa pouco; que se compra por preço baixo.
>   "parecia ouro, mas era um metal v."
>
> 3.
>   que inspira desprezo, não tem dignidade; abjeto, desprezível, indigno, infame.
>   "v. traidor"
>
> Origem
>   ⊙ ETIM lat. vīlis,e 'que é de baixo preço, barato'

Vil, antes sinônimo de barato, módico, significa hoje maligno, desprezível, ignóbil.

A semelhança da trajetória histórico-linguística dessas três palavras é da transição de um sentido relativo à simplicidade, à plebe, para algo pejorativo.

Como, e por que essas e outras palavras tiveram seus sentidos de frugalidade transformados em negatividade?

Comment: Acho que esta pregunta é um pouco ingênua. Centenas de palavas de origem látina mudaram de sentido. A única maneira de saber é ir palavra por palavra em textos antigos passando pelas diferentes épocas ou étapas da língua até chegar à modernidade. Uma tarefa que eu pelo menos não pretendo emprender. Boa sorte! :)

Comment: Sua solução é ingênua e absurda, como esperado. O contexto histórico para a etimologia das palavras seria suficiente.

Comment: Claro, e o "contexto histórico" se procura em livros publicados durante o percurso das étapas da história da língua portuguesa. Justamente, identificar estes textos é uma tarefa bem pesada.

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria que o cerne da resposta não é epistemológico, mas sim semântico.

O que é comum não é especial; o que é simples não é sofisticado. Mesmo quando o latim era língua viva, o habitante da vila era considerado menos importante que o habitante do castelo, e o preço era também uma medida de valor.

Não entrando no mérito do valor da simplicidade (e de quanta sofisticação pode ser necessária para apreciá-la), é natural que se valorize o que custa trabalho: e é preciso esforço para se obter o refinado do bruto, ou para se ter algo diferente do que se costuma ter, do ordinário.

Comment: Agradeço a tentativa de respota, ela elabora sobre a valorização daquilo que é sofisticado, porém não adentra no tópico central que é a transformação do [simples] em [mal].

Comment: @WilliamLio, Acho que não fui claro: defendo que não houve tal transformação de significado, mas sim que ambas as acepções coexistem: qualquer palavra com uma conotação de simplicidade pode ser usada com sentido negativo.

Answer (score 1):

Questão interessante, que no meu entender ultrapassa a mera questão semântica e se encontra no domínio da psicologia coletiva. Atentai que o processo não ocorre apenas na língua Portuguesa, o que indicia que o processo é mais geral e não propriamente particular. A palavra inglesa *rude* além de significar "ofensivo" ou mesmo "rude", também significa, de acordo com o [dicionário Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rude), *lacking sophistication*. Em Francês temos a palavra *vulgaire*, que além de significar apenas "vulgar", dito a uma mulher tem um significado bastante ofensivo. A resposta a este processo encontra-se, no meu entender, não na linguística, mas na psicologia grupal e talvez na sociologia.

Uma teoria (a partir daqui são apenas suposições e opiniões pessoais) pode advir do facto de, numa sociedade, as pessoas tenderem a valorizar o que é raro e não o que é abundante, da mesma forma que o ouro é mais precioso que o chumbo, sendo que do ponto de vista físico-químico são apenas elementos químicos com números atómicos diferentes. Assim, a natureza do "mau" assinalada pelo consulente, estará mais relacionada com a quantidade, do que propriamente com a simplicidade inerente. Sempre houve mais vilões e plebeus que aristocratas ou patrícios; os eventos extraordinários são muito mais raros do que os ordinários, e as peças de baixo custo são muito mais abundantes que as caríssimas.

Comment: Como um adendo, poderia se dizer que as classes 'mais raras' também tinham acesso aos bens materiais igualmente mais raros, intensificando ainda mais a relação. Gostei da resposta, porém não dou 'green check' pois não possui substanciação externa. Ademais, elementos como o ouro não são mais caros apenas pelas leis de mercado, mas também por suas propriedades como a mínima reatividade (demora eternidades para enferrujar), brilho (mais um motivo para ser utilizado como adorno), e boa condutividade elétrica.

Comment: Obrigado. Repare que o ouro já é preciso muitos milhares de anos antes da descoberta da corrente elétrica. Mas sim, tem outras propriedades como o brilho. Mas em qualquer caso o que o torna valioso é mesmo a sua raridade.